# Apache Ni-Fi expression using ifElse function and condition defined with equals() function returns wrong results for true values

Tags: apache-nifi

I am working at an Apache Ni-Fi flow that fetches data from a MySQL database and, after some data transformations, it writes data into a Timescale (postgreSQL) database.

I use UpdateRecord 1.15.2 processor to do the data transformations. Those include adding the column /mvalue whose value is calculated according to the following expression:

```
${metric:equals(18):ifElse(${valueSum}, 9)}
```

What should happen is that, when the value of column metric is 18, then mvalue should take the value of the column valueSum. Else, the value should be 9.

However, this is not what I get since I get the value 9 for all the rows.

metric is a renamed column that in the original MySQL database is int(11) and in the target database is smallint.

valueSum is double in MySQL and numeric in postgreSQL.

the new calculated column mvalue is numeric in postgreSQL.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Bernardo

Comment: Is `metric` an attribute or a record field? It needs to be the former to use Expression Language, otherwise you'd need a RecordPath expression like `/metric`

Comment: Metric is a field. However, if I modify the expression by using "/metric" I get the following error: "UpdateRecord[id=xxx] Failed to process StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=yyy,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1645093871442-1, container=default, section=1], offset=55522, length=991],offset=0,name=cb38fcab-a593-400b-b929-0b6a938d90f2,size=991]; will route to failure: Invalid Expression: ${/metric:equals(18):ifElse(${/valueSum}, 9)} due to Unrecognized token at line 1, column 2. Query: ${/metric:equals(18):ifElse(${/valueSum}, 9)}"

Comment: I also set Replacement Value Strategy: Record Path Value in the processor

Comment: Then I changed the rule as follows: /metric:equals(18):ifElse(/valueSum, 9) and I got the following error: UpdateRecord[id=xxx] Failed to process StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=yyy,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1645093871442-1, container=default, section=1], offset=64675, length=1069],offset=0,name=ec900411-9544-4caf-8ac0-e826d006ca8b,size=1069]; will route to failure: Unexpected token '(' at line 1, column 14. Query: /metric:equals(18):ifElse(/valueSum,9)

Comment: I don't see that recordpath supports `ifelse`. Try just to use replaceRegex: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#replaceregex

Comment: Setting Replacement Value Strategy: "Record Path Value" means that you have to use RecordPath expression. The problem is that there is no ifElse function there. How to build complex logic using RecordPath expressions? Or alternatively, how to extract the value of a filed in a Expression Language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **QueryRecord** processor:

- `update` (dynamic attribute): `SELECT *, CASE WHEN metric=18 THEN ${valueSum} ELSE 0 END AS mvalue FROM FLOWFILE`